# Both are scale 1, one is a lot smaller

Tags: unity, c#

[image]

Both of these balls are the same scale (1) but one is a lot bigger.

What can cause this? I don't think I've ever scaled the ball anywhere in my code.

Comment: There is a million ways to do this and you aren't giving us much to work with. Is one of the spheres the child-object of something?

Comment: Yes, oh my god. I had no idea the sphere would scale with the parent. Thanks. You can put it as the answer and I'll select as best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scale of the transformation of an object also affects all of its children. Make sure the scale is identical throughout the whole object hierarchy of your scene-graph.